# How to get the data as a promise while saving?

Tags: angularjs

I getting the data from ng-model from html->controllers->services->Factories
After saving i got response is like this

This my response

```
Resource {_id: "56fe5ddc414e823023576508", productcode: "101",  productname:"desktops",
__v: 0, isDeleted: false…}
$promise:undefined
$resolved:true
__v:0
_id:"56fe5ddc414e823023576508"
isDeleted:false
productcode:"101"
productitems:Array[1]
productname:"desktops"
__proto__:Object
```

myFacory code:

```
factmodule.factory("DashboardItemFactory",function($resource){
var ProductItemnew=[];
    ProductItemInfoResourec=$resource("http://192.168.0.194:9070/productitems/:id", 
                    {"id": "@id","productid":"@productid"}, {update: {method: "PUT"}});
return{
    addProductItemnew:function(itemslist){

        var items = new ProductItemInfoResourec(itemslist);
        items.$save({"id":itemslist.productid},function(respdata){
            console.log(respdata)
            ProductItemnew.push(respdata);
            console.log("Data Saved...")
        },function(respdata){
            console.log("Error while saving the data");
        });
    },

}

})
```

Please help me how make the data as promise..

Comment: Does save function uses angular's $http method? if yes, return ProductItemNew from inside the save funtion, then return items.$save. addProductIntemNew should return a promise.

Comment: not working..will you please add the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is working  for me with $q

```
factmodule.factory("DashboardItemFactory",function($resource,$q){
var ProductItemnew=[];
ProductItemInfoResourec=$resource("http://192.168.0.194:9070/productitems/:id/:itemid", 
                    {"id": "@id","productid":"@productid"}, {update: {method: "PUT"}});
return{

    addProductItemnew:function(itemslist){

         var dfr = $q.defer();
        var items = new ProductItemInfoResourec(itemslist);
        items.$save({"id":itemslist.productid},function(respdata){

            console.log(respdata)
            ProductItemnew.push(respdata);
             dfr.resolve(ProductItemnew);
            console.log("Data Saved...")
             return dfr.promise;

        },function(respdata){
            console.log("Error while saving the data");
        });

    }
}

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return promise object from the factory method. Resources have `$promise` property which is what you need. So it could be something like this:

```
factmodule.factory("DashboardItemFactory", function($resource) {

  var ProductItemnew = [];

  ProductItemInfoResourec = $resource("http://192.168.0.194:9070/productitems/:id", {
    "id": "@id",
    "productid": "@productid"
  }, {
    update: {
      method: "PUT"
    }
  });

  return {
    addProductItemnew: function(itemslist) {

      var items = new ProductItemInfoResourec(itemslist);
      return items.$save({ id: itemslist.productid }).$promise.then(function(respdata) {
        ProductItemnew.push(respdata);
        console.log("Data Saved...", respdata)
        return respdata; // or return ProductItemnew;
      }, function(respdata) {
        console.log("Error while saving the data");
        throw new Error("Error while saving the data")
      });
    }

  }

})
```

Just decide what you want this promise to resolve with: either original response from save request or maybe `ProductItemnew` array.

Comment: thankyou for your response.i used  $q. it is working for me. i will try this also

Comment: You should not use $q and defer in this case, this is called [deferred anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns).

Comment: Ok. Thank you you for your suggestion. i will go with promise